# is there any query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

table name games

| player_id | event_date | games_played |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-03-01 | 5 |
| 1 | 2016-05-02 | 6 |
| 1 | 2017-06-25 | 1 |
| 3 | 2016-03-02 | 12 |
| 3 | 2018-07-03 | 5 |

Result table:

| player_id | event_date | games_played_so_far |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-03-01 | 5 |
| 1 | 2016-05-02 | 11 |
| 1 | 2017-06-25 | 12 |
| 3 | 2016-03-02 | 12 |
| 3 | 2018-07-03 | 17 |

Comment: I assume to OP wants to have games_played summed up cumulatively as games_played_so_far.  The close votes and downticks seems to be a bit brutal to a new contributor!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH CTE(player_id, event_date,games_played) AS
(
  SELECT  1 , '2016-03-01' , 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT  1 , '2016-05-02' , 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 , '2017-06-25' , 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 , '2016-03-02' , 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 , '2018-07-03' , 5  
)
SELECT C.player_id,C.event_date,C.games_played,
 SUM(C.games_played)OVER(PARTITION BY C.player_id ORDER BY C.Event_date ASC)games_played_so_far
FROM CTE AS C
ORDER BY C.player_id
```

If this solution is not applicable to snowflake then please google something like "running total for snowflake"

Comment: This function works for Snowflake, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` function for getting cumulative sum

```
select
    player_id,
    event_date,
    sum (games_played) over (partition by player_id order by event_date asc) as games_played_so_far
from
    games;
```

[Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum.html)

SQL for creating Dataset

```
create table games 
 (player_id int ,  event_date  date,  games_played int ) ; 
 
 insert into games values (1 , '2016-03-01' , 5 );
insert into games values ( 1 , '2016-05-02', 6 );
insert into games values (1 , '2017-06-25' , 1 ) ;
insert into games values ( 3 , '2016-03-02' , 12) ;
insert into games values ( 3 , '2018-07-03' , 5 ) ;
```

Result

```
PLAYER_ID   EVENT_DATE  GAMES_PLAYED_SO_FAR
1   2016-03-01  5
1   2016-05-02  11
1   2017-06-25  12
3   2016-03-02  12
3   2018-07-03  17
```